# Ping to Floating IP of an OpenStack instance answers with Request timeout for icmp_seq

Tags: openstack, icmp, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon, floating-ip

I am new to OpenStack and the whole cloud-world, also I don't have any experience in setting up a server via terminal. (So please write a beginner-friendly answer :D) I did the following steps:

1. I have setup OpenStack on an VM with Ubuntu 18.
2. I made an instance with an cirros0.5.2 image
3. I followed this [tutorial](https://opensource.com/business/14/9/test-wordpress-4-openstack) to understand how to setup an application on OpenStack (they use wordpress)
4. After I did the network setup like in the tutorial (setup a router, connect the private network to the public one, added floating IP to the instance) I wanted to ping the floating ip 172.24.4.188, but I receive 'Request timeout for icmp_seq'.

Now I tried several things to fix it:

1. I checked my Mac OS firewall, switched it off -> nothing changed
2. I changed the security group rules liked [this](https://arpitapatel.wordpress.com/2017/06/21/not-able-to-ssh-or-ping-openstack-floating-ip/) -> nothing changed
3. I also tried to follow this [here](https://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-rdo/launch-instance-private.html) but the openstack commands like `nova flavor-list` in the terminal shows the error:
   `ERROR (CommandError): You must provide a user name/id (via --os-username, --os-user-id, env[OS_USERNAME] or env[OS_USER_ID]) or an auth token (via --os-token)`

My terminal skills are super poor, so I don't really understand why I need to add a user here, when I can login to the dashboard. Would be great if someone could explain me how to debug this network issue and why I don't receive an answer from my floating ip. THANK YOU!

Comment: When you login to the dashboard, you provide a user and a password. The dashboard then determines other parameters like domain and project. On the command line, you have to provide all that; the usual practice is putting all information in shell variables. Instructions: https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/wallaby/install/keystone-openrc-ubuntu.html.

Comment: As to why your floating IP doesn't work, there are hundreds of possible causes. How did you create the cloud, and which version of OpenStack did you install?

Comment: With poor Linux command line skills, you will probably bounce from one problem to another at high frequency (pinball). I suggest you learn that, plus basic Linux system administration and a bit more than basic Linux networking.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I actually followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpk4i66-IU4 to setup openstack on ubuntu 18 (as recommended somewhere in the openstack guide). I installed the most recent openstack version like described here: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

Comment: From where do you ping? From MacOS or from Ubuntu? By default, Devstack's external network is a fake external network; in reality, you can only reach it from the Devstack host. Also, 127.* are [loopback addresses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses); such an address can't reach another device in principle. What is your `local.conf` file? Did you use 127.something as HOST_IP?

Comment: Yes, HOST-IP should be the address of the main network interface. Still, I don't understand why your Floating IPs are in the 127 range. You could probably use port forwarding to access Devstack's floating IPs from the host, but I don't know how to do that on MacOS. The real solution is attaching the cloud's *public* network to a network that MacOS can reach: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/networking.html#locally-accessible-guests.

Comment: I just saw I had a flipped number in the IP adress: the floating IP starts with 172 not 127. I tried to reach that one via the ubuntu vm again, but I didn't work too.

Comment: When I am changing the local.conf  file do I have to run something again?

Comment: local.conf is the file that configures the deployment of Devstack. This means that changing it now, after deployment, has no effect. You need to run stack.sh. However, before running stack.sh, I recommend you reinstall Ubuntu to ensure no settings of your current cloud remain. Start from a clean slate.